# Postfix block all but one IP as sender

Tags: postfix, email-server

I'm trying to setup an additional Postfix smtpd service on a non-standard smtp port, which allows smtp auth without TLS to support an old printer which cannot use TLS (to send scans and reports via email). However, this printer should still provide a valid username and password.

This is the service definition in `master.cf`:

```
50025     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o smtpd_tls_auth_only=no
  -o { smtpd_client_restrictions=check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/printer_whitelist,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject }
```

And `/etc/postfix/printer_whitelist`:

```
8.8.8.8 OK
0.0.0.0/0 REJECT
```

In theory this should

- reject all clients that don't have the IP `8.8.8.8`
- allow `8.8.8.8`, but only if it authenticates successfully

In practice, the `printer_whitelist` table does not seem to work properly. I have tried `0.0.0.0/32 REJECT`, `0.0.0.0 REJECT`, `* REJECT` in addition to the reject defined above.

How can I match all clients to be rejected after the `OK` rule?

Comment: The printer is so old it can't use the standard submission port?!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, you did use `postmap` to create the .db file after making your printer_whitelist file right?

Comment: @Appleoddity Yes, I did

Answer (score 0):

Using `cidr:/etc/postfix/printer_whitelist` instead of `hash:/etc/postfix/printer_whitelist` fixed this issue.